# Ошибка компиляции «Undefined symbols» для шаблонного метода

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

При компиляции, возникает ошибка. Требуется сделать функцию сортировки с "*универсальным*" аргументом.

---

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> ```
> "void selection_sort<float>(float*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
> ```
>
> _main in main.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see >invocation)

---

**selectionsort.hpp**

```
#ifndef selectionsort_hpp
#define selectionsort_hpp

#include <stddef.h>
#include "swap.hpp"

template<typename T>
void selection_sort(T[], size_t);

#endif /* selectionsort_hpp */
```

**selectionsort.cpp**

```
#include "selectionsort.hpp"

template<typename T>
void selection_sort(T array[], size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        size_t minimal = i;
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[minimal] > array[j]) {
                minimal = j;
            }
        }
        swap(array[minimal], array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шаблонные функции, в отличие от обыкновенных, нужно полностью определять в header'е.

Дело в том, что шаблон — не функция, это лишь намётка для компилятора на то, как должна выглядеть функция с тем или иным аргументом-типом. Поэтому когда компилятор компилирует `main.cpp`, он видит только header, и не может сгенерировать код конкретной реализации шаблонной функции для вашего типа аргументов. А когда он компилирует `selectionsort.cpp`, он тем более не может этого сделать, потому что он в этой точке вообще не знает, с какими параметрами будет компилироваться шаблон в других файлах.

А вот если вся функция расположена в header'е, то при компиляции `main.cpp` компилятор видит реализацию функции, и может её скомпилировать.

Comment: Где-то это уже прочитал, но не понял, что нужно сделать 

Comment: @Niki-Timofe: Как что? Унесите реализацию шаблонной функции в `selectionsort.hpp`. Файл `selectionsort.cpp` удалите из проекта полностью.

Comment: [Так?](https://imgstore.herokuapp.com/img/56f47cad0170220003000001.png)

Comment: @Niki-Timofe: Ага, вроде бы так.

Comment: А, все, просто там еще две функции было, сначала показалось, что ничего не изменилось. Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe: Пожалуйста!