# Определение шаблонных функций в другом файле

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Как определить шаблонную функцию внутри другого файла?

Например, у меня есть объявление

```
template <typename type>
type minimum(type, type);
```

в файле `foo.h`. Как определить эту функцию в файле `foo.cpp`?

Если написать в `foo.cpp` просто

```
template <typename type>
type minimum(type first, type second)
{
    return (first > second ? second : first);
}
```

, то вылазят всякие страшные и непонятные ошыбки.

Comment: и ещё 1 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506442/Почему-компилятор-выдает-ошибку/506444#506444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тела шаблонных функций следует размещать только в заголовочных файлах *.h

Comment: Нужно создать отдельный хедер для шаблонных функций или оставить в `foo.h`?

Comment: @baran - это уже на ваше усмотрение.